# SOAPServer+php+iis v6 (not correct closing tag)

Tags: php, iis-6, soapserver

thanks for reading. I am having a big problem using the SOAPServer class from php.

when we make the test we have this respons, that works well:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:WSDL" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns1:NotificacionClienteResponse>
             <NotificacionClienteReturn xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <NotificacionCliente>
                   <RESULTADO>
                      <CODIGORETORNO>8</CODIGORETORNO>
                      <DESCRIPCIONRETORNO>Xml incorrecto</DESCRIPCIONRETORNO>
                   </RESULTADO>
                </NotificacionCliente>]]>
             </NotificacionClienteReturn>
          </ns1:NotificacionClienteResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but when we do the same, but in other server, we have this response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:WSDL" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
           <ns1:NotificacionClienteResponse>
               <NotificacionClienteReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
                   &lt;NotificacionCliente&gt;
                      &lt;RESULTADO&gt;
                         &lt;CODIGORETORNO&gt;8&lt;/CODIGORETORNO&gt;
                         &lt;DESCRIPCIONRETORNO&gt;Xml incorrecto&lt;/DESCRIPCIONRETORNO&gt;
                      &lt;/RESULTADO&gt;
                   &lt;/NotificacionCliente&gt;
                </NotificacionClienteReturn>
           </ns1:NotificacionClienteResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope
```

as you can see in the second respons there are 3 different problems:

- it appers &lt and &gt in place of < and >
- at the end of the xml its missing de >
- and the xml its not formated (i did it for you :) )

Information about the server:

- same wsdl, web server, php_soap.dll, php.ini
- we use iis v6 and php v5.2.9-2
- the php is calling the SOAPServer this way, in both servers:

  new SOAPServer($Path, array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'))

well, any information you can tell us or any clue you might think its worth tring just tell it... 
of course, the same if you need more information.

thanks you all in advance!

Comment: Please, correct formatting, especially the code part. If you want others to read it, don't make it harder.

Comment: Ari, i have correct the format, thanks!

Comment: I have the issue with missing the ending '>' using: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) and php 5.4.45-0+deb7u1. Tried various encodings - didn't help. If the message is not long (as in lots of bytes in the soap envelope) it doesn't happen.